# In text citation of multiple works should show author only once followed by the year of the other works

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, apacite, quotation

I am currently writing a paper and am struggling with the citations.

```
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
%Bibliographie hinzufügen
\addbibresource{references.bib}
%abstand zwischen einträgen der Bibliographie
\setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}
```

This is my BibLaTeX code - unfortunately whenever I enter a citation:

```
\autocites[pp. 10-11]{NetflixInc.2002NetflixReport}[pp. 10-11]{NetflixInc.2003NetflixReport}[pp. 11-12]{NetflixInc.2004NetflixReport}
```

Instead of getting

> (Netflix Inc., 2002, p. 10-11, 2003, pp. 10-11, 2004, pp. 11-12)

it compiles to

> (Netflix Inc., 2002, pp. 10-11; Netflix Inc., 2003, pp. 10-11; Netflix Inc., 2004, pp. 11-12).

How can I fix this error?

I'm scared of switching to `natbib`, because I do not want to redo all the citations in this paper.

PS: In addition, does BibLaTeX automatically sort the in-text citations by year/name or not?

PPS: This is an example `.bib` file so you can reproduce the error:

```
@online{netflix-no-date,
    author = {{Netflix}},
    title = {Netflix - Environmental, Social & Governance - Committee Membership},
    url = {https://ir.netflix.net/governance/committee-membership/default.aspx},
}
@online{netflix-2000,
    author = {{Netflix}},
    date = {2000},
    title = {Netflix - Financials - Annual Reports & Proxies},
    url = {https://ir.netflix.net/financials/annual-reports-and-proxies/default.aspx},
}
@online{netflix-2001,
    author = {{Netflix}},
    date = {2001},
    title = {Netflix - Overview - Top Investor Questions},
    url = {https://ir.netflix.net/ir-overview/top-investor-questions/default.aspx},
}
```

Comment: Depending on the selected style `biblatex` can sort citations in the same pair of curly braces. But it cannot sort across different curly braces. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/817.

Comment: Double check the correct output with the APA manual and report this as a bug at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/. (I personally find the citations without author harder to parse if they involve page references.)

Comment: Note that your example entries do not match the example citation call you gave. In fact the example entries will cause errors if cited because the `&` is not correctly escaped to `\&`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks! Will report it. According to APA7 everything should be cited like I suggested. Although it looks worse in my opinion! Thanks for the `\&` comment. I'm importing my citations from mendeley I guess that's another problem to report...